# Laravel with Aruba Cloud Storage

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-s3, storage

No way to make Laravel storage working with Aruba Cloud Storage (S3).
I've tried all the combinations but still nothing.

**config/filesystems.php:**

```
    's3' => [
        'driver' => 's3',
        'key' => 'XXXXX', // ARUBA STORAGE USER
        'secret' => 'XXXXX', // ARUBA STORAGE PASSWORD
        'region' => 'r1-it.storage.cloud.it', // ARUBA SERVICE URL
        'bucket' => 'XXXXX', // BUCKET MANUALLY CREATED ON WEBSTORAGE
        'url' => 'r1-it.storage.cloud.it', // ARUBA SERVICE URL
        'endpoint' => 'https://r1-it.storage.cloud.it',
        'use_path_style_endpoint' => false,
    ],
```

**TestS3Controller**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Storage;

class TestS3Controller extends Controller
{
    public function test(){
        return Storage::disk('s3')->get('test.txt');
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, did you manage to get it working? I'm also considering whether to integrate it...

Comment: This link (https://kb.cloud.it/storage/object-storage/usare-un-account-storage/s3browser.aspx) talks about permission management, maybe it can be useful.